# Open pantheon terminal with starting command

Tags: pantheon-terminal, command-line

How can I open `pantheon-terminal` with starting command to be executed? For example something like `pantheon-terminal --start-with echo "Hello World!"` should open new terminal window and execute the `echo "Hello World!"` command in it.

Is it possible to make something like that?

Comment: Can you expand on your use case as it's possible to have commands run when a shell starts (e.g. .bashrc), but your use case may be specific to using a terminal window in a particular context?

Comment: I don't want to run command everytime terminal starts. I wanted to make script that prepares my web testing enviroment (run selenium and node.js server). I wanted each of then run in separate terminal window for crash reports etc.

Comment: If your issue is resolved, please mark the answer as **Answer** that helped solving your problem. If you have solved this on your own, please write it down as answer and mark it so.

Answer (score 2):

With `io.elementary.terminal`, which seems to be the new name, you might be able to do this using the `-e` flag. I've done something very similar with `xfce4-terminal -e` before, maybe that helps when looking for examples around the web. You can find this option in the manpage.

Comment: how do you pass commands to it -e doesn't work. -T doesn't set title either.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been quite a while, but..
Put the command you want it into the ~/.bashrc file.

Comment: Welcome to eOS:SE. Could you expand on your answer with an example in code? This will make it easier for people in the future to solve a similar problem and offer a reason for people to upvote your answer 